# Where does PayPal query send?

Tags: magento2, checkout, paypal-payflow-pro

I want to find in code place, where PayPal query sends, with Payflowpro Credit/Debit card payment method on checkout. Please, help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a place where exactly PayPal Payflow sends request from Magento to PayPal gateway then you need [\Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflow\Service\Gateway::postRequest](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/Payflow/Service/Gateway.php#L60) method. This method uses curl to perform all operations, like authorize, capture, void, etc.

But if you need the place, where Magento sends request from payment card form to PayPal, you need to look through [app/code/Magento/Paypal/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/payflowpro-method.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Paypal/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/payflowpro-method.js#L79).

Comment: Yes, I have researched payflowpro-method.js, but could't find exact place with PayPal request, only processing of placeOrderHandler. And, how I understand, this handler is changed somewhere. Do you now, where?

Comment: What exact request do you need?

Comment: Where credit card data is sent to PayPal. Actually, I need to change card number because my format is 0000-0000-0000-0000, and required only numbers. So I find where can do it.

Comment: You are not able to do it because PayflowPro integration uses Magento Transparent Redirect, that means all card fields are rendered in the iframe and directly will be sent to PayPal gateway.

Comment: I know, and want to change field itself after click Place Order but before it sends to PayPal.

Comment: You will not have access to cc fields because they are rendered in the iframe.

Comment: Why? I have access just by id. Now checked it, I can change field. I mean input filed in cc-form.

Comment: Yes, you can get access to html input, but can't access cc fields in the additional data, that what I meant. If you want to change html input, you can just extend PayflowPro payflowpro-method.js and override `placeOrder` method.

Comment: So if I change input in the begin of placeOrder method, it will solve my problem, right?